# how to train and test model with data one by one?

Tags: python, machine-learning

For example, I have data below:

```
ten train data:
1.txt
2.txt
...
10.txt

two test data:
11.txt
12.txt
```

I usually set these data in one piece:

```
train_data = load_file(train.txt)   #include 1.txt  2.txt  ....  10.txt
test_data = load_file(test.txt)     #include 11.txt 12.txt
```

Then using:

```
X_train, y_train = preprocess_data(train_data, tokenizer)
X_test, y_test = preprocess_data(test_data, tokenizer)  
#preprocess_data is one function I decide to preprocess data
```

Then train and test model in usual way.

I want to ask how to train the model with data above one by one

```
(first train model with 1.txt,
 then train model with 2.txt,
...
finally train it with 10.txt)
```

and test it one by one:

```
(first test 11.txt
 then test 12.txt)
```

should I use `X_train[i][j], y_train[i][j]`
specifically, please tell me how to use it?

Comment: You could put the txt in one folder. Then with glob and a for loop you loop through each file and for each file you train your model and output the performance (or save the output performance parameters into a list variable).

Comment: thanks, I'll try it. But first I might learn the 'glob' package.

Answer (score 0):

## train-test split evaluation random forest on the sonar dataset

#Tying this together, the complete example is listed below.

````py
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
# load dataset
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/sonar.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(url, header=None)
data = dataframe.values
# split into inputs and outputs
X, y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]
print(X.shape, y.shape)
# split into train test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
# fit the model
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# make predictions
yhat = model.predict(X_test)
# evaluate predictions
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, yhat)
print('Accuracy: %.3f' % acc)```
````

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand. Where did this method train and test data one by one?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).